# Passing a function with arguments to `addEventListener`

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a single function that works for multiple selections. I'm creating a selection screen of a video game that should work like this: https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~meestej005/eind/

The way I achieved this was with this code:

```
function character1(){
for (var i = 0; i < sprite.length; i++){
    sprite[i].classList.remove('charSprite');
}
sprite[0].classList.add('charSprite');
hadouken.play();
}
```

I made this function 4 times, one for each character. They are called with this:

```
char1.addEventListener('click', character1);
```

Right now, I want to create a function that does this for each character. This is what I came up with:

```
function character(name, music){
for (var i = 0; i < sprite.length; i++){
    sprite[i].classList.remove('charSprite');
}
name.classList.add('charSprite');
music.play();
}

char1.addEventListener('click', character(charSprite1, hadouken));
```

Sadly, this doens't work. Clicking one of the characters now results into absolutely nothing, not even an error. So I'm doing something wrong, but have no idea what. I want to fix this using only Javascript. I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` takes a function as its second argument. When you invoke the function like `character(charSprite1, hadouken)`, you are no longer passing that function reference around (instead, you are passing the result of that function, which is being called *immediately* rather than when an event fires). I would suggest capturing the `name` and `music` arguments using closure, and returning a function each time from `character`:

```js
function character(name, music) {
  return function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sprite.length; i++) {
      sprite[i].classList.remove('charSprite');
    }
    name.classList.add('charSprite');
    music.play();
  }
}

char1.addEventListener('click', character(charSprite1, hadouken));
```

Comment: I'm beginning to understand more how this works, thanks. But what do you mean by closure? And what function should I return?

Comment: Read more about closure [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work#111111). `return function` in the code I posted above is the part of this solution that allows you to "capture" `name` and `music`.

Comment: Perhaps an easier alternative would be to pass a binding.

Comment: @RaymondChen `bind` can get ugly if you ever end up wanting to use `this`, but I see your point.